# Suppose we're playing a basketball game in a hyperbolic space. What are some of the noticeable differences?

Tags: soft-question, hyperbolic-geometry

I've been doing some (novice level) reading into non-Euclidean geometry, and while I can sort of grasp at the mathematics involved, I'm having trouble visualizing exactly what is going on. I have searched up renderings and played with a few simulations of hyperbolic space, but I find all of them quite abstract in that they simulate shapes and platonic solids rather than things we'd expect to see in our Euclidean lives.

So my question is this: What would be some of the differences in a standard game of basketball in a hyperbolic space (say with a Gaussian curvature of $-1$), compared to a basketball game in our world? I'd imagine that gravity would be quite messed up because we have to change some notions with distance (but I don't know how), but what about potential changes in strategies? How would you guard someone? Or shooting? Where would the nets be placed and what would the court look like?

Feel free to change the sport to whichever one you'd prefer.

Comment: You might have problems, for a start, because the further away from you the ball gets, the wider apart it is stretched by the underlying space. (This is just a guess. I don't really know about the mechanics of hyperbolic objects. A Euclidean-space object which was somehow transported into this world might be torn apart merely by travelling, but I don't know how hyperbolic-space objects would react.)

Comment: Almost everything would be more difficult because, as others have said, the area of a surface of a given distance away from a point grows exponentially, not geometrically, so ... playing outfield in hyperbolic baseball would be rough. :)

Comment: Have you tried HyperRogue? For your question, the Ivory Tower (a land in HyperRogue) is especially relevant, as it shows how gravity in the hyperbolic plane could work.

Comment: Gaussian curvature has units of "per length". For example, you say that the curvature is $-1$ per foot. Just $-1$ does not make sense (unless your basketball court is also dimensionless).